# Android Studio codestyles/Project.xml Configuration

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am struggling with configuration of project.xml of android project. I want to follow the coding style mentioned in this file and I don't want Android Studio to add any stuff in this file itself.

**Problem**

While working on the project Android studio add following lines in itself.

```
 <option name="PACKAGES_TO_USE_STAR_IMPORTS">
    <value>
      <package name="java.util" alias="false" withSubpackages="false" />
      <package name="kotlinx.android.synthetic" alias="false" withSubpackages="true" />
      <package name="io.ktor" alias="false" withSubpackages="true" />
    </value>
  </option>
  <option name="PACKAGES_IMPORT_LAYOUT">
    <value>
      <package name="" alias="false" withSubpackages="true" />
      <package name="java" alias="false" withSubpackages="true" />
      <package name="javax" alias="false" withSubpackages="true" />
      <package name="kotlin" alias="false" withSubpackages="true" />
      <package name="" alias="true" withSubpackages="true" />
    </value>
  </option>
```

Is there any way that I can prevent android studio from adding these lines? I have tried different methods to do that but unable to produces the desire results.

This is the actual `project.xml` file that I want to follow

```
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <code_scheme name="Project" version="173">
    <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="150" />
    <DBN-PSQL>
      <case-options enabled="true">
        <option name="KEYWORD_CASE" value="lower" />
        <option name="FUNCTION_CASE" value="lower" />
        <option name="PARAMETER_CASE" value="lower" />
        <option name="DATATYPE_CASE" value="lower" />
        <option name="OBJECT_CASE" value="preserve" />
      </case-options>
      <formatting-settings enabled="false" />
    </DBN-PSQL>
    <DBN-SQL>
      <case-options enabled="true">
        <option name="KEYWORD_CASE" value="lower" />
        <option name="FUNCTION_CASE" value="lower" />
        <option name="PARAMETER_CASE" value="lower" />
        <option name="DATATYPE_CASE" value="lower" />
        <option name="OBJECT_CASE" value="preserve" />
      </case-options>
      <formatting-settings enabled="false">
        <option name="STATEMENT_SPACING" value="one_line" />
        <option name="CLAUSE_CHOP_DOWN" value="chop_down_if_statement_long" />
        <option name="ITERATION_ELEMENTS_WRAPPING" value="chop_down_if_not_single" />
      </formatting-settings>
    </DBN-SQL>
    <JetCodeStyleSettings>
      <option name="NAME_COUNT_TO_USE_STAR_IMPORT" value="2147483647" />
      <option name="NAME_COUNT_TO_USE_STAR_IMPORT_FOR_MEMBERS" value="2147483647" />
      <option name="CODE_STYLE_DEFAULTS" value="KOTLIN_OFFICIAL" />
    </JetCodeStyleSettings>
    <codeStyleSettings language="XML">
      <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="300" />
      <indentOptions>
        <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
      </indentOptions>
      <arrangement>
        <rules>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>xmlns:android</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>xmlns:.*</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
              <order>BY_NAME</order>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>.*:id</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>.*:name</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>name</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>style</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>.*</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
              <order>BY_NAME</order>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>.*</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
              <order>ANDROID_ATTRIBUTE_ORDER</order>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>.*</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>.*</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
              <order>BY_NAME</order>
            </rule>
          </section>
        </rules>
      </arrangement>
    </codeStyleSettings>
    <codeStyleSettings language="kotlin">
      <option name="CODE_STYLE_DEFAULTS" value="KOTLIN_OFFICIAL" />
      <option name="FIELD_ANNOTATION_WRAP" value="0" />
    </codeStyleSettings>
  </code_scheme>
</component>
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: nvm it is bug in latest android studio https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39937 Android-Studio V.4.0.1

Comment: Thank you a lot @zeeshan-shabbir for this answer. Do you care to make this comment an answer so other people can see it more easily? Otherwise I can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it was an issue in Android-Studio V.4.0.1 [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39937](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39937) which has been resolved in latest Android Studio